# rails using has_many and belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Alright, I'm going to try to explain this as best as possible:

I have two models

employer.rb

```
class Employer < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :listings

end
```

listing.rb

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :employer

end
```

Employers login through the `employers_controller` and listings are created through `listings_controller`

I'm having trouble getting the id from the employer table being inserted into the employer_id column in each individual created listing. I hope this makes sense. If anyone has any advice, it would be much appreciated. I have a feeling this is because I'm doing this outside of the employer_controller, but not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: And how are you creating your listings now?

Comment: Through the listings controller -- do I need to call certain helpers from the employers controller into the listings controller?

Comment: I was looking specifically for your code.

Comment: it's just the standard rails generate scaffold code, one text field, is there something I should add to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) If you are not dealing as nested resource then

When you render the new action of Listing controller, you know for which employer (@employer) you want to create the listing.

So render a hidden field for employer_id using a hidden_field or hidden_field_tag

```
hidden_field_tag 'employer_id', @employer.id()
```

2) If you are dealing as nested resource and your route looks something like
/employers/:employer_id/listings/new / (Get) && /employers/:employer_id/listings

Then in create action

```
@employer = Employer.find(params[:employer_id])
@employer.Listing.new(params[:listing]
```

Comment: This is what I wanna do (number 2) -- I can't figure out how to nest listings into the employers controller -- so I made a new controller. Any quick suggestions or links? Thanks!!

Comment: Check this out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources. You can check this screencast http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources. Also you can find lot of info id you google for nested_resources

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the employer id in your session, since they need to login to create the listing. I won't use the param from the view, then its easy for one employer to create a listing as if it was created by another employer, just by changing the id value in your hidden field. Here's what is possibly a better approach:

```
@employer = Employer.find(current_user.id)
@employer.Listing.new(params[:listing]
```